# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '([String : Any]) throws -> Bool'

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have 2 Array of Dictionaries and I want to check if second array of dictionary's one dictionary in present in first array of dictionary or not.

```swift
let dicA = [[String:Any]]()
let dicB = [[String:Any]]()

if dicA.contains(where: dicB[0]) {
   print("Contains")
}
else {
   print("Not Contains")
}
```

// it's giving me syntax Error like this:-

- Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '([String : Any]) throws -> Bool'

Comment: if dicA.contains(where: dicB[0])) {
  
You have a double closing bracket here, that is the error.

Comment: This question should be close as caused by a simple typo.

Comment: its not the typo

Comment: The typo is one problem, but not the only one.

Comment: You guys are right but I want to check second array of dictionary's any of element( [String:Any] ) is in first array of dictionary or not?

Comment: @AsmaGodil You have to define a criteria for a dictionary comparison. One can compare `keys` but what about `values`?

Answer (score 2):

Array's `contains` method declaration is like this:

```
func contains(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

Which means your `where` predicate can't be a single argument. It should be a closure like this:

```
if dicA.contains(where: { (element) -> Bool in

    return false

}) {

} else {

}
```

Replace the logic in the closure to return which elements you need.

Comment: You guys are right but I want to check second array of dictionary's any of element( [String:Any] ) is in first array of dictionary or not?

Comment: @AsmaGodil To write a equability logic, we need to know the fields of your dictionary. Anything unique so that we can compare?

Answer (score 1):

Take your time when coding. An unnecessary `)` in your `if` statement was one the causes.

```
let dicA = [[String:Any]]()
let dicB = [[String:Any]]()

let element = dicB[0]

if dicA.contains(where: { (element) -> Bool in
    print("Contains")
    return true
}) {
}
else {
   print("Not Contains")
}
```

Comment: You guys are right but I want to check second array of dictionary's any of element( [String:Any] ) is in first array of dictionary or not?

Comment: It shouldn't still compile. you can't set a variable like that to `element`. It represents a single element in the receiver.

Comment: so is there any solution for my question please?